# How to deal with "is there productX on Ethereum?"

Tags: discussion

"List-like" questions are usually off topic for

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for
>   Ethereum Stack Exchange as they tend to attract opinionated answers
>   and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far
>   to solve it."

How should we deal with questions of the form like "is there a product or service that does X in Ethereum?", examples:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9660/is-there-a-decentrazlied-exchange-for-trading-other-currencies-on-the-ethereum-p

[Are there any android wallets for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/835/are-there-any-android-wallets-for-ethereum)

Some options:

A) Close as off-topic

B) Ask for question to be edited to "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"; then close as off-topic if question isn't edited.

C) Convert to community-wiki

D) Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is value in this kind of question. If we were describing the Internet today to someone who had never heard of it, "Is there $THING on the Internet?" would be a reasonable question. (Can you buy stuff on the Internet? Sure: Amazon, eBay, Etsy, etc...) In our case, the fact that "Is there any decentralized exchanges?" is so frequently asked (here or elsewhere) that it would seem remiss to ignore it.

On StackOverflow, how questions like "Are there any production-grade non-SQL databases in existence?" or "Is there any option other than virtual machines for virtualization" handled? They're a legit question, even if they'd be prone to arguments over details.

Comment: I think the proper question for Stack Exchange would be _"How to $THING on the Internet?"_

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior should depends on the purpose of the question, if it to promote a product (Spam like) or is it just a help request (noobs are always confused). choosing which tool to use or book to read needs the opinion of the others whom will share their personal experiences ad opinions and like-so anyone reading the answers will discover new solutions.

I think it might be beneficial to answer such question,e.g if by reading such discussion someone discover a tool that he wasn't aware of. However, if the question has an underlying purpose like to promote a special product it should be closed.

Comment: People who want to promote something aren't the ones who necessarily ask the question: they look at what questions they can use to answer and add their stuff.